# Create a clone of an item in a list2 - Update list2 columns when there are changes in list1

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate

I would like to ask you about the following flow.
I have a list (**list1**) that

- first I run a flow to update status columns based on some conditions (from blank to "pending") and then
- I need to create a clone item in an other list (**list2**) & the columns that have status as "pending" (in **list1**), select in **list2** from dropdown "-".

Then, I want to run an other flow:

- When a status column in **list1** changed to "Done", update the specific item in **list2** from "-" to "pending"

I'm still not very familiar with power automate, I've tried many combinations of triggers and actions but I can't find the solution. Thank you very much for your time. You help is much appreciated!!

Flow to Create the Item in **List2**, after the necessary updates (this flow works):
[image]
Flow to Update **List2** Columns with the right results:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. When an item of **List1** is created or modified, check whether the Status column of that item is having value or not (i.e. not blank).
2. If it is having value and the value is 'Pending' then create its clone item in **List2**. Save that List2's item ID in List1's item column (e.g.: Clone Item ID).
3. Now, whenever there is any change in the item of **List1**, first check that there is change in its Status or not.
4. If there is any change in *Status* and *Status* value is 'Done' then use the "Clone Item ID" column value to get the cloned item from **List2** and then update the status of that item to 'Pending'

---

Edit

Use ***Update Item*** action for **List2**. In "Id" field provide "Clone Item ID" (i.e. ID = CloneItemID) and in "Status" field provide 'Pending'. This will update the clone item in **List2**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! 
I created the column "Clone item ID" in List1 (id of the item in List2), I used the conditions: "Has Column X changed AND Column X value is equal to "Done" but I don't know how to use the second part of step 4 "then use the "Clone Item ID" column value to get the cloned item from List2 and then update the status of that item to 'Pending' ". What actions should I use into the condition to get the cloned item from List2?

Comment: Please refer the edit I made in the answer.

Comment: There is not option in the ID field (action: Update Item) to select the "Clone item ID " column. In the ID filed, I can only select the ID of  actions "get items" & "when an item is modified".

Comment: Okay, then save the "Clone item ID" of the current item of List1 in a variable  and then use that variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works!!